# Copy recursively X folders deep linux

Tags: linux, copy, directory

I want to copy a folder to another folder, but I want only 2 layers deep..
I know I can do cp -rf ... ... but this will copy all the layers...

Example ( The folders name are just an example)

I have 
Book/science/1/ext
And I want to copy it, but only Book/science/1

I don't want the 3rd layer, Is it possible?

Thank You.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for superusers.  And probably should be migrated over there.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I think it's an even better match for the [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Comment: This is true, the only reason why I mentioned super users is that SO can automatically migrate to it, and it's also on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Elliot's answer works for me, but makes an intermediate archive. If you want to do it without one the commands:

```
find src-dir/ -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec mkdir -p dest_dir/{} \;
find src_dir/ -maxdepth 3 -type f -exec cp {} dest_dir/{} \;
```

Will recreate the directory structure under dest_dir, and then look for all of the files in src_dir that are less than three levels deep and copy them to the structure in dest_dir (note the /{} after dest_dir in both commands).

It will miss symbolic links and I'm really bad at the maxdepth and mindepth options, so they might be off by one.

Comment: The archive is only in memory, and it enables block copy!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'd be interested to find out whether the block copy makes up for the time spent creating and unpacking the archive, but I'm too lazy to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is one possible way using `find` and then tar to perform the copy in a block way and to keep the directory structure

```
find . -maxdepth 3 | grep -v "^.$" | xargs tar cfp - | \
    (cd /destination_folder ; tar xvvf -)
```

Comment: I am sorry, But I do not understand the code and how to modify it so it will fit to my situation ( I do understand what you are trying to do)

Comment: @Oren What you asked for. Recursively copy from the current folder (the '.' in the find command) to the destination_folder (the argument to the `cd`) all files up to two folders deep from the current folder.

Comment: @Oren *and then tar to perform the copy*.

Comment: There isn't one, that's why it's cool. You just pack up the structure in an archive and extract it elsewhere.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not quite sure what the point of the `-name "*"` bit is though. Won't that just match everything? And if so, why have it?

Comment: it does not work.. this is the code that I use:
 find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*" | xargs tar cfp - |     (cd ../ ; tar xvvf -)

Comment: @genisage Yep. Edited to remove. It's not necessary.

Comment: @genisage Has anyone tried it.. I get files 4 levels deep even if I use -maxdepth 1

Comment: You have any idea why using this code I get 4 levels deep 
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*" | xargs tar cfp - | (cd ../ ; tar xvvf -)

Comment: @Oren You're picking up ".", Edited to remove that entry.